# Traffic Light Time Delay in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

Is there anyone that knows how you can apply a time delay to a traffic light for a single phase only? Or a time offset?
The delay function is not available for the traffic light class. Also `turnOn` and `turnOff` functions, even timed, do not offset the timing of the traffic light. Keep in mind that the "On Phase Change" functions do not target a specific phase of the light, but work in a global loop on all the phases.

Thanks,
Octav

Answer (score 0):

You can define all phases as having infinite duration and control your delays using the function `switchToNextPhase()`

With this you have absolute control of your traffic light delays and you can skip a phase or multiple phases by using the switchToNextPhase() many times in a row.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, the switchToNextPhase function does not work properly for me, or, most likely, i am using it wrong. I have attached here a screenshot from the current setup. Like so, even with only one line, it simply locks the simulation and loops infinitely through the phases. What i want to know is how can i set a specific time delay between the switching of the phases?

https://imgur.com/a/Vq2vHa4

Thanks

Comment: you can't do that on the "on change phase" action... you need to do it somewhere else.... What I would use is a dynamic event to do that (from the agent palette)